# How to exclude characters from express-validators escape() function

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, validation

I am using check from express-validator to validate user input and am wondering if I can exclude characters from the test? I have

```
check("profile.about").trim().escape()
```

which converts any characters used in HTML to their equivalent HTML entities but it is causing undesired results if a user enters an apostrophe. Is there any way of filtering the apostrophe out of the `escape()` method? If not does anyone have any hints on how I could mimic `escape()` and just drop the `'`. Thanks

Comment: Its a weird question. Because allowing apostrophe will expose you to sql injection and cross site scripting attacks. Which will make the escaping pretty useless.

Comment: Why would you like to keep the apostrophe?

Comment: @yonbav I am using a noSQL database so is that still an issue? I have other profile fields including adding favorite authors and it looks really silly if a user enters the name O'Brian for instance

Comment: I cant really tell if it will be an issue depends a lot on how you implemented your server. Any way i would recommand to use unescape before you return the value to the user

Comment: Check out this link https://flaviocopes.com/express-sanitize-input/

Comment: So escape before going in the DB and then unescape before adding to the DOM? Won't this allow HTML to be added to the DOM? Thanks for the help am just getting used to this aspect

Comment: Im not sure I understood the question. There is no problem with html added to the DOM. The problem starts when your site does not know how to tell the differance between user input and html tags. If that happens the user can enter something like "<script>alert(‘XSS’)</script>" and add a mellicous script. And if it gets to your database it can even effect other users if you select that data from your db to other users

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible to add another middleware immediately to accomplish this...

`unescape-middleware.js`

```
module.exports = (escaped, char) => function (req, res, next) {
    unescapeCharacter(req.params, escaped, char);
    unescapeCharacter(req.query, escaped, char);
    unescapeCharacter(req.body, escaped, char);
    return next();
}

function unescapeCharacter (obj, escaped, char) {
    for (const key in obj) {
        // Replace the escaped version with the character
        obj[key] = obj[key].replace(new Regex(escaped, "g"), char);
    }
}
```

This is then used like so...

`app.js`

```
const { check } = require("express-validator");
const unescape = require("./path/to/unescape/middleware.js");

app.get(
    "/some/route", 
    check("profile.about").trim().escape(), 
    unescape("&#39;", "'"), 
    require("./path/to/router/handler.js")
);
```

I believe this should solve the issue...